# How to construct multiple id values to a curl request

Tags: php, curl

To explain more.   I have a current data-store which will feed a .json file from a remote server.  I can grab this remote file through an id added to a curl function.

ie.  $json_url = 'example.com/datastore.json?id='. $result['id'].'';

This example is housed within a foreach loop pulling the id's from a database. This json_url example works for requesting 1 id at a time.  I have instituted on the remote server the ability to request multiple ids at once through comma separated values.

ie. `$json_url = 'example.com/datastore.json?id=1,id=2,id=3`

Now if I am building the json_url on the fly for multiple requests, how should I do this?

I want this type of a $json_url result:

```
`$json_url = 'example.com/datastore.json?id=1,id=2,id=3`
```

BUT those id values are id values that have been returned from the foreach loop, and with each id value comes an added json file and an added id value to the json_url.  In this case instead of 1, it is 3 .json files I will have retrieved with 1 request to the server, the number here is ambiguous as it is ultimately dependent on how many id values are found on the query.

If I am unclear with my examples, let me know and I will take the time to make it more clear.

```
                `
```

Comment: So, do you also control the server that outputs JSON or is that external (ie: out of your hands)?

Comment: Yes, I can control the server that outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using an array?:

```
$json_url = 'example.com/datastore.json?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

then you can loop using

```
foreach($_GET['id'] as $key => $val){}

//$_GET['id'] OR $_POST['id']...
```

Comment: I think I am going to stick with comma seperated values, as its tried tested and true.

Comment: @Brandon Why would want to do that? This answer shows the right way to do it. But if you think sticking commas there is "tried tested and true" why did you bother asking the question in the first place?

Comment: I misread what his answer was. Looking at it now, after sleep, is the way I want to do it.